# Assign a value to ContractLineItem

Tags: apex, contracts

Probably dumb question, but I'm in cognitive dissonance.
I want to create ContractLineItem from Account's Assets. I go to setup=>Contract line items and check fields. There's a lookup on Product2.
[image: ContractLineItem Fields]

I've tried to assign ContractLineItem.Product2  but on compile it says that "Incorrect Product2 field for sObject...". I went to workbench and, to my surprise, didn't find the product2Field here.
[image: Workbench]

I've tried to create a ContractLineItem record without Product2 reference and it requires PriceBookEntry from me.
First question is - how is it possible that I have a product2 field in setup, but I don't see it in workbench?
Second - how to get correct priceBookEntry? The only way I see is to parse priceBookEntries for the Product and then compare prices from priceBookEntry with AssetPrice. If equals - assign this priceBookEntry to ContractLineItem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOAP API guide shows fields for the ContractLineItem records .Its clear that you need priceBookEntryId to associate and there is no way to associate to Product2 .

A product2 can have multiple pricebookEntry records depending on the number of pricebook you have defined .

Hence a contract line item can have multiple records for a single Product depending on the PriceBook .

If you have just one pricebook then that will be your default pricebook and you can query for the pricebookEntry with default pricebookId and Product2Id and assoicate that to the contractLineItem .

If  you want multiple associations ,then you can query for all the pricebookEntries with given Product2 Id and associate with the ContractLineItem .

Comment: Thank you, understood the logic. But still two surprising things: 1. How did they do that?2.For other Items(QuoteLineItem, OpportunityLineItem) there're both fields - Product2Id and PriceBookEntryId. Only for this item there's a...fake Product2Id field.

Comment: Even in QuoteLineItem and OpportunityLineItem they are read only now .PricebookEntry is whats accepted now

Answer (score 0):

In the Salesforce model, an Opportunity, Order or ServiceContract is related to one single price book (Pricebook2) : this means that all products added to an Opp, to an Order, or to a ServiceContract are priced with 1 single price book.

So, the key to finding the correct line item is Product Code + Pricebook id (Product2.ProductCode + Pricebook2.Id) : you can easily find the PricebookEntry and add it to the ServiceContract line.